# Some .oints and numbers

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

**What short word is missing in the puzzle below? Explain your reasoning.**

---

```
                .6    .2.3   .1.4    .1.1.3   .2.4    .3   .8    .9   .3    .1.1   .1.4   .3    .8    .1.1.3   .1.1.1   .2.4    .1.2.2    .8   .1.2    .1.2.2    .2.2    .8     0.   .1.1.3    .2.4    .1.2.2     .8   .2.4    .1.4
```

---

*No knowledge required except some trivial.*

Comment: Is the big space at the beginning intended?

Comment: @RonchenLuo No, not intended

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The missing word is:

> **DAY**

The dot ...

> ... represents *p*, which can be seen from the title, where the word "points" is rendered as ".oints". We can also see that numbers in a "word" are increasing, that numbers can occur more than once and that if there are several numbers in a "word", they are small, most frequently ones and twos. And the dot (or *p*) comes before all digits, but after the zero.

So what do the numbers mean?

> Now imagine the numbers as indices:
>  *p*<sub>6</sub> , *p*<sub>2</sub> *p*<sub>3</sub> , *p*<sub>1</sub> *p*<sub>4</sub> , ...
>
>  Here, *p*<sub>*n*</sub> represents the *n*-th prime number:
>
>  `.1  .2  .3  .4  .5  .6  .7  .8  .9`
>   `2   3   5   7  11  13  17  19  23`
>
>  Juxtaposition of variables means multiplication, so the first three terms are:
>
>   *p*<sub>6</sub> = 13
>   *p*<sub>2</sub> *p*<sub>3</sub> = 3 · 5 = 15
>   *p*<sub>1</sub> *p*<sub>4</sub> = 2 · 7 = 14
>
>  Can you see where this is going?

Each term ...

> ... represents a letter: The product of prime numbers is the index of a letter in the alphabet: 13, 15, 14 represents the letters M, O and N.
>
>  The whole expression resolves to:
>
>   **MON TUES WEDNES THURS FRI SATUR SUN**
>
>  These are, of course, the days of the week with the small word **DAY** missing from each.
>
>  (The term `0.` represents the letter A with index 1, which cannot be represented as a product of prime numbers. Perhaps 0 *p* means "no prime". Anyway, that's a special case.)

Comment: That's the word, great job!